# Cloudwatch: monitor average NetworkIn across EC2s in an auto-scale group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to create a cloudwatch metric that monitors the average `NetworkIn` across all the EC2 machines in an auto-scale group.

Is this possible?  It seems that I might be able to monitor the total `NetworkIn` in various ways, but I want to monitor the average.  The reason is that I want to add nodes to the auto-scale group when per-node network traffic is above a threshold, for an application whose bottleneck is networkIn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it is possible:  You can use the `AutoScalingGroupName` dimension and `Average` statistic and it will average across all nodes in the auto scaling group.  Here's the command I used:

```
mon-put-metric-alarm ALARM-NAME --comparison-operator GreaterThanThreshold \
--evaluation-periods 2 --metric-name NetworkIn --namespace "AWS/EC2" \
--dimensions "AutoScalingGroupName=AUTOSCALE-NAME" --period 60 \
--statistic Average --threshold 30000000 \
--alarm-actions arn:aws:autoscaling:etc-etc-etc-scaling-policy
```

Comment: This seems to be an answer to my own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20570750/

Comment: Is it possible to use not AWS/EC2 but "Linux System" (my own) metrics with auto-scaling groups? Which namespace should I use?